# I want to bring a custom domain to my Azure website

Tags: azure, dns

I am currently using the basic type azurewebsite url for my site: http://NAME.azurewebsites.net. How do I add the domain name into Azure?

My settings won't let me add a domain that I own.

My name provider says I need a CNAME entry and a verification.

Most of the guides I found use the old portal.

Are there any differences and

How do I get the CNAME entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding a custom domain to your an Azure webapp it must not be using a free subscription. It has to be shared, basic, or standard at least.
It wont allow you to access the custom domain entry if on a free sub.

The CNAME entries and A records will be done on your name provider management account.

When using the new portal follow the below steps to find the custom domain menu.

1. Settings
2. Under the heading "Routing"
3. Custom domains and SSL
4. Bring external domain

A guide on Azure custom domains can be found here: [Azure Custom Domains](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/)

The IP address listed at the bottom of this menu will be used as the @ (Address, A) record.

Open your NameCheap management account and procced to the advanced DNS setting of your domain name.
Here the records need to be configured as follows:

```
HOST NAME     IP Address/URL                         Record Type
@             <the IP address from Azure>            A
www           <website>.azurewebsites.net.           CNAME
awverify      awverify.<website>.azurewebsites.net.  CNAME
awverify.www  awverify.<website>.azurewebsites.net.  CNAME
```

Fill the details in specific to your site and save the records.
It may take some time for the records to propogate, give it an hour or so.

You can confirm it using this tool [Digwebinterface](http://digwebinterface.com/).

Once you have confirmed the records are updated, go back to the custom domain menu in Azure and add your .com and save.
The domain will now be usable by your web app. Dont add the www. infront of it.

In my personal experience, if everything looks right according to the guides and its still not working, just give it a day and try again. The records might not have fully updated.

If you are using a free subscription and for some reason cant change to shared, basic or standard. Then you can use url frame from the namecheap panel instead of the custom domain records.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!